# Dropbox CORS cannot download file

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm following this guide https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_download_zip

I've problem when using api dropbox and want to get download files.
first is about cors problem.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download_zip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer myTokenAcess';
$headers[] = 'Dropbox-Api-Arg: {\"path\":\"/myfolder/mysubfolder/mysubfolderagain\"}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

and the results is

> Error in call to API function "files/download": Bad HTTP
>   "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Expecting
>   one of "text/plain", "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
>   "application/octet-stream", "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8".

then I'm trying to add this line on header

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
```

the results be

> Error in call to API function "files/download": HTTP header
>   "Dropbox-API-Arg": could not decode input as JSON

and then I'm trying to change `drobox-api-arg` line to

```
$headers[] = 'Dropbox-Api-Arg: json_decode({\"path\":\"/myfolder/mysubfolder/mysubfolderagain\"},TRUE)';
```

and the results still same like above

> Error in call to API function "files/download": HTTP header
>   "Dropbox-API-Arg": could not decode input as JSON

can someone help me to fix this?

Update : 
@sideshowbarker results using this

```
$headers[] = 'Dropbox-Api-Arg: {"path":"/myfolder/mysubfolder/mysubfolderagain"}'
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$headers[] = 'Dropbox-Api-Arg: {"path":"/myfolder/mysubfolder/mysubfolderagain"}'`? That is, without the double-quotes escaped.

Comment: I have changed my question to show the results of your given code

Comment: So yeah that looks like binary data — a zip file, I guess? So it seems like the download of the content succeeded. You got a stream of bytes back. I suppose you now need to have your code write that stream of bytes to a file named *something*.zip somewhere

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with CORS btw. (at least not based on the code and the error messages you have shown.)

Comment: Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". is called cors right? read this desc https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats . 'Browser-based JavaScript and CORS pre-flight requests' @misorude

Comment: what different with this"? https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_download_zip @sideshowbarker you mean we need to convert it as zip ?

Comment: _“Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". is called cors right?”_ - no, it is not. You are not even making the request from any sort of client that would implement CORS here. CORS applies to requests made inside the browser, using a client-side scripting language like JavaScript - not at all what you are doing here to begin with.

Comment: ok, my bad. but no problem i've found the answer and i post already thanks @misorude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer based on @sideshowbarker say. I just need to conver bytes into zip 
so i just add this line at end line and now this working fine.

```
foreach($result as $byte)
{
    $byteString .= $byte;
}
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=tesFolderQ.zip");
echo $byteString;
```